# How to show pages in Mat-Paginator in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using `mat-paginator` from [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api) component in an Angular 8 app, working, and looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

I didn't find any documentation on how to do this using this component. Is there a native way to do it using `mat-pager` or is there any other component that is more complete and can show pages?

*Edit:* I'm using this on a Material table, so I have `dataSource`, not a product list.

Comment: MatPaginatorModule does not have a way to show a button for every page.

Comment: @Carsten really bad to know :( Any other suggested component?